# Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents.dll' or one of its dependencies. The filename or extension is too long

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am using a Windows Azure Worker role. When the worker role starts, I get this error. When I get the error, I get a dialog that says OK and continue. I click continue and the worker role starts. The assembly is located here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.1\ref\WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents.dll

1. Will this error happen on my local system only? I want to send this code to my production server, but will it prevent the roles from starting?
2. I tried clearing my temp ASP.NET files in the .NET 4 folder and the error persists. Is this a temporary error?

Comment: What is the FULL path to where the file is on your development system?

Comment: Of course, the follow on question is : What's the FULL path to where the file will end up on your production system? If you can answer these questions, the answer will probably present itself.

Comment: OK I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents assembly should be installed in the GAC by the SDK installation.  My guess is that you have a component targeting SDK 2.1 (thus WindowsAzureTelemtryEvents.dll v 2.1) but you only have Azure SDK 2.2 installed.  Can you confirm this?  You can also browse to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents and see which versions of that file are installed on your machine.

Comment: It says WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents version is 2.11. I don't have a 2.2 assembly. If I deploy this to the server, will this cause the worker roles to stop?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a bad SDK install as this DLL is not meant to be referenced by your code and is part of the guest agent.  Maybe try uninstalling and reinstalling the Azure SDK?

Comment: I upgraded to 2.2 and it solved the issue. Right click on the cloud service and go to properties. Click upgrade on the first screen.

Comment: This issue reappeared on my machine many times. I used Fusion and Process Monitor to debug and it turns out that I referenced 2 assemblies from WindowsAzure SDK 2.1 that got installed by nuget. As well I found in the process monitor that vs searches for AzureTelemetry inside the GAC of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime\v4.0_2.2.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35, and so placed the WindowsAzureTelemetryEvents there. I hope this is done now.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown the Azure compute emulator.
Restart Visual Studio

Comment: In my case sometimes even a restart of windows was necessary.

Comment: and removing older versions of the sdk seems to help, I removed all other sdks on my machine and let only version 2.2 installed.